# What is the best way to mock out collaborator in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have got a class:

```
class myclass:
     def __init__(self):
         self.collaborator = Coll()

     def tested_method(self):
         val = self.collaborator.val
         val_2 = self.collaborator.get_val2()
         ....
```

And one way to mock out collaborator is this way

```
class TestMainModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mock_c = mock.Mock()
        mock_c.val = 12
        mock_c.get_val2 = mock.Mock(return_value=13)
        self.sut = myclass(mock_c) # pass as argument
```

or

```
class TestMainModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mock_c = mock.Mock()
        mock_c.val = 12
        mock_c.get_val2 = mock.Mock(return_value=13)
        self.sut = myclass()
        self.sut.collaborator = mock_c # set when sut is created but quite bad when collaborator is loading files from disk or takes more time to create?
```

or

```
class TestMainModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mock_c = mock_collaborator()
        self.sut = myclass(mock_c) # pass as argument

    class mock_collaborator: # use new class
        val = 12
        def get_val2(self):
            return 13
```

or maybe use @mock.patch and do not pass it as argument?

Is there one proper way or mocking out collaborators it does not really matter?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way is dependency injection.

```
# MyClass
def __init__(self, collaborator=None)
    self.collaborator = collaborator or Coll()


from unittest.mock import create_autospec, Mock

def setUp
    mock_c = create_autospec(
        Coll,
        get_val=Mock(return_value=12),
        get_val2=Mock(...),
    )
    self.sut = myclass(collaborator=Coll)
```